# Can't log in to my virtual box Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: kali-linux

I just installed Kali Linux 2.0 on VB and I can't seem to remember the username and it's telling me the password I entered is incorrect. How do I fix this?

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224043/cant-log-in-to-kali-linux-and-cant-reinstall-anything?rq=1

Comment: »» I just installed Kali Linux 2.0 on VB «« : Well, then reinstall, and write a note on paper with your password. -

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change the default password and you forgot the password that you set, just reinstall it. If you didn't set a password during the installation, the default credential are:
username:`root`
password: `toor`